# Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true after upgrading ServiceStack app to NetCore 3

Tags: servicestack, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

After upgrading a ServiceStack based api app from NetCore 2.x to NetCore 3.0, my Angular app is receiving errors from the api when the server tries to return the response from what I can see.

```
ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler: 2019-10-25 21:50:26,248 [22] DEBUG ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler - CreateRequestAsync/requestParams:
ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler: 2019-10-25 21:50:26,249 [12] DEBUG ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler - CreateRequestAsync/requestParams:
ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost: 2019-10-25 21:50:26,276 [4] ERROR ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringMethod()
```

Any tips as to what this issue is?

Comment: Can’t identify it from that StackTrace, if you can put together a stand-alone repro next can take a look.

Comment: If I switch EnableRequestBodyTracking to false it works, if its True then that throws the error.  An issue serialising the request body.  I'm using the CsvRequestLogger.

Comment: In that case can you download the latest v5.7.1 on MyGet as it's sounds like the [GetRawBody() issue in .NET Core 3.0](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/netcore-3-0-getrawbody-could-not-load-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-internal-bufferinghelper/7883) which has since been resolved.

Comment: That was it - thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to v5.7.1 as per @mythz excellent suggestion.

"In that case can you download the latest v5.7.1 on MyGet as it's sounds like the GetRawBody() issue in .NET Core 3.0 which has since been resolved."

Comment: Update: I had this error still running ServiceStack 5.8.1 with NetCore3.1 on a couple of service methods that were uploading files in the request.  You wouldn't really want to log the request body anyway in this scenario so I excluded those request DTO types from the logging.